# Skipping Bytes During Stream Read

Tags: c#, streamreader

Was curious if it was possible to skip bytes during a stream read of a binary file? I'm trying to read in 32 bytes then skip the next 6 bytes all the way and repeat all the way towards the end of the file. Size of file is around 10mb. Here's the relevant code I have right now where I'm getting an out of bounds error.

```
            byte[] tempBuff = new byte[FlashSize];
            int numBytesToRead = FlashSize;
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while(bytesRead <= numBytesToRead - 38{
                    ecmStream.Read(tempBuff, 0, 32);
                    ecmStream.Seek(6, SeekOrigin.Current);

            }
```

edit:

Thanks to Henk I also realized I need to skip 14 bytes after I read in every 10000. Is parsing on the fly with a stream still a good option at this point?

Comment: I believe you need to add a check to see if you are counting past the available bytes.

Comment: @MarcGravell They are sorry. I just edited.

Comment: Is `FlashSize` 32 bytes or the size of the file? Per [pm100's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52598798/9362652) answer, it seems you are reading the entire `FlashSize` from the stream into offset 32 of your `byte[] tempBuff`. In other words, the loop would execute exactly once if it wouldn't first encounter an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exeception` due to starting at offset 32 instead of 0.

Comment: The test file is a little over 2 million bytes. I see where I went wrong with the first read and why I would be getting an out of bounds error. I would want to read 32 bytes then skip 6 all the way toward the end.

Answer (score 1):

your first read is wrong

```
ecmStream.Read(tempBuff, 32, FlashSize);
```

should be

```
ecmStream.Read(tempBuff, 0, FlashSize);
```

That first int says which offset in tempBuff to read into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netframework-4.7.2